# How generate a range of numbers using underscore.js with leading 0s?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I've been trying to generate values for a dropdown where the user is to select hours, minutes.

To get the possible values of minutes, I was using this:

```
_.range(1, 61)
```

This generates an array like

```
[1, 2, 3 ... 60]
```

but I require it to be of form

```
[01, 02, 03 ... 60]
```

Is there a clean way to getting this using underscore?.

Comment: Numbers don't have leading zeros.

Comment: @Marty My bad. I don't know why I didn't think of that before posting. But ya, strings of numbers is fine for my usecase.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In FF, and soon in other browsers, use [`padStart`](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-string-pad-start-end):

```
_.range(1, 61) . map(num => String(num).padStart(2, '0'))
```

Another approach would be

```
_.range(1, 61) . map(num => ('0' + num).slice(-2));
```

This tacks a zero on the beginning of all the numbers, but then takes just the last two characters of the result.

A functional approach would be to write a higher-order function which takes the length and returns a function which pads its input to that length:

```
function make_padder(len) {
  return str => ('0000000000000' + str).slice(-len);
}
```

Now you can write

```
_.range(1,61) . map(make_padder(2))
```

Comment: The second approach is good enough for my usecase, thanks! Marking this as accepted answer since I was looking for the cleanest way possible.

Answer (score 1):

Place this at the top of your javascript file ...

```
Number.prototype.pad = function (count) {
   var num = this.valueOf();
   var ret = "";
   for (var i = 0; i < count - num.toString().length; i++) {
       ret += "0";
   }
   ret += num;
   return ret;
}
```

Then return ...

```
_.range(1, 61).map(function (num) { return num.pad(2) })
```

This will give an array of strings with leading 0s of length 2

Comment: Interesting way of doing it. I learnt something new today, thanks!

Comment: Some words about Augmenting built-in objects. **Object-Oriented JavaScript - Second Edition**: Augmenting built-in objects through the prototype is a powerful technique, and you can use it to shape JavaScript in any way you like. Because of its power, though, you should always thoroughly consider your options before using this approach. The reason is that once you know JavaScript, you're expecting it to work the same way, no matter which third-party library or widget you're using. Modifying core objects **could confuse the users and maintainers of your code and create unexpected errors**.

Comment: You're welcome, Abhinav I. I've learnt to not meddle with the javascript Object.prototype because for some reason, it conflicts with jQuery. However, I've gotten some pretty good advantages off extending the String, Array and Number prototypes. It just makes life simpler.

Comment: The problem with extending the Number prototype is that you cannot say `1.pad()` because of parsing issues, and instead have to say `1 .pad()` or `1..pad()`.

Comment: Thanks @AliMamedov. I can see how people could get confused with this approach. I'ts just that modifying the inbuilt types was something I never thought was not possible. I guess I will stick to using an easier approach as suggested by torazaburo. Also thanks Ikechi.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible only with array of strings:

```
var 
  range = _.range(1, 61),
  i,
  arr = [];

for (i in range) {

  if (range[i] <= 9) {

    arr.push('0' + range[i]);
  }
  else {

    arr.push('' + range[i]);                      
  }
}
```

Result:

```
console.log(arr); // ["01", "02" ... "61"]
```

> [**Object-Oriented JavaScript - Second Edition**](https://www.packtpub.com/web-development/object-oriented-javascript-second-edition) When a number starts with a 0, it's considered an octal number. For
>   example, the octal 0377 is the decimal 255:
>
> ```
> var n3 = 0377;
>
> typeof n3; // "number"
>
> n3; // 255
> ```
>
> The last line in the preceding example prints the decimal
>   representation of the octal value.
>
> ```
> parseInt('0377', 8); // 255
> ```
>
> ECMAScript 5 removes the octal literal values and avoids the confusion
>   with `parseInt()` and unspecified radix.